# Add transparency to GoogleMap plot (loa package)

Tags: r, plot, transparency, geocoding

I'm trying to use this plot of `loa` package:

```
GoogleMap(z ~ lat*lon,col.regions=c("red","yellow"),panel=panel.contourplot)
```

Here you can find the objects:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47720440/loaPackage.RData

This is the resulting plot:
[image]

But I need to add transparency to this plot, so I can see what there is behind the colored region. How can I do this?

Comment: The documentation suggests argument `alpha.regions` might do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I might do it with 8 digit hexmode, but Roman was right.

`png(); print( GoogleMap(z ~ lat*lon,col.regions=list("yellow","red"), alpha.regions=list(alpha=.5, alpha=.5) ,panel=panel.contourplot)  );dev.off()`

`[1] "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=45.5774096970577,12.540287147873&zoom=9&size=640x311&maptype=terrain&format=png32&sensor=true"`

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I tried `alpha.regions`, but I didn't used it like you. In my code there was `alpha.regions=0.5`, so it was an error